# Error during upload image to imgur - inavlid URL

Tags: image, filereader, imgur

i have some troubles with imgur api. I converted image to base64 code and tried upload it to imgur api. Unfortuatelly I'm receiving an error:

```
"error": "Invalid URL (data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..."
```

Here's my function:

```
uploadImageToImgur: function (file) {
const url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
      reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = async function () {
    let { result } = reader;

    try {
      const request = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Authorization": 'my client key',
        },
        body: result
      });

      const response = await request.json();
      console.log(response);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You need to cut this part out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some parameters. Also, make sure your headers have the Client-ID key.

```js
const request = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": 'Client-ID {yourKey}',
  },
  form: {
    "image": result,
    "type": "base64"
  }
});
```